# How to read a binary file to a structure in C

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles

I have this structure called **product** that I am trying to read from a binary file to fill in this function:

```
void reading(FILE *fp){

  Product *obuff = malloc(sizeof(Product));
  fread(obuff->code, sizeof(obuff->code), 1, fp);
  fread(obuff->name, sizeof(obuff->name), 1, fp);
  fread(obuff->quantity, sizeof(obuff->quantity), 1, fp);
  fread(obuff->price, sizeof(obuff->price), 1, fp);   

  printf("%s %s %d %.2f\n", obuff.code, obuff.name, obuff.quantity, obuff.price);
}
```

when I try to compile I get errors saying that I cannot pass arguments because of wrong data types. Is there a way to read to structures from Binary files or am I just doing something wrong here?

Structure:

```
#pragma pack(2)
struct product {
   char code[15];
   char name[50];
   short int quantity;
   double price;
};
#pragma pack()

typedef struct product Product;
```

Comment: Unless you generated the file from exactly the same `struct` and on exactly the same system (same ABI, same endianess), using proper marshalling with shifts and bitops is the better way.

Comment: It's not good practice to edit the answer into the question because it is now confusing for people seeing the question for the first time. It would be better to roll back your edit, accept the answer, then post a new question about the new error. BTW including a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will get more useful answers.

Comment: @M.M my mistake. I'll do it right now.

Comment: @sd I think you should consider changing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass *pointers* to have `fread()` read data.

```
void reading(FILE *fp){

  Product *obuff = malloc(sizeof(Product));
  fread(&obuff->code, sizeof(obuff->code), 1, fp);
  fread(&obuff->name, sizeof(obuff->name), 1, fp);
  fread(&obuff->quantity, sizeof(obuff->quantity), 1, fp);
  fread(&obuff->price, sizeof(obuff->price), 1, fp);

  printf("%s %s %d %.2f\n", obuff->code, obuff->name, obuff->quantity, obuff->price);
  free(obuff); /* free whatever you allocated after finished using them */
}
```

Comment: oh I see. thank you. It compiles but when I execute it has a segmentation fault around the **fread** statement for **obuff->name**

Comment: @sd Have you ever used `valgrind`? It's very easy, and I highly recommend it when you run into segfaults. In this case I think you've run into some stack or heap corruption (meaning the cause of the segfault lies somewhere other than the code you've provided) or you're lying to `printf` by telling it `obuff->code` and `obuff->name` are strings when they aren't (as far as we can see).

Answer (score 1):

**There are several problems with this code.** Some of them will prevent compilation, and others might cause erratic behaviour. Since the erratic behaviour is something you might not notice, I'll cover that first.

---

**You should always check the return value of `malloc` before you attempt to use it.** For example:

```
Product *obuff = malloc(sizeof *obuff);
if (obuff == NULL) {
    /* obuff can't be used because allocation failed */
    return;
}
```

**On a related note, as MikeCAT suggested, you can avoid leaking memory by using `free`** when you're finished with anything you've `malloc`'d, `realloc`'d or `calloc`'d...

**On another related note, you also should not use the values `obuff->code`, `name`, `quality` and `price` unless the return value of `fread` indicates success.**

---

```
fread(&obuff->code, sizeof(obuff->code), 1, fp);
fread(&obuff->name, sizeof(obuff->name), 1, fp);
```

**This will compile, however you don't need the ampersands (`&`)** and in fact shouldn't use them here. The expressions `obuff->code` and `&obuff->code` both point at the same place (because `obuff->code` is an array) but the type of object that they point at is different; `obuff->code` points at the first byte of the array while `&obuff->code` points at the entire array.

---

```
fread(&obuff->quantity, sizeof(obuff->quantity), 1, fp);
fread(&obuff->price, sizeof(obuff->price), 1, fp);
```

**This will compile, and to clarify you *do* need the ampersands here, however having said that `short int` and `double` may have different representations on different systems.** You need to form a consistent representation within the file by *serialising* these fields. Serialisation is a lengthy topic more suitable for a chapter in a software design book, so for the sake of brevity I'll move on unless further specific questions are raised about this topic here.

---

```
#pragma pack(2)
```

This is non-portable and there's no real need for it in the code you've provided.

---

```
printf("%s %s %d %.2f\n", obuff.code, obuff.name, obuff.quantity, obuff.price);
```

**It is expected that `%s` corresponds to a pointer to a string;** a string is a sequence of characters that ends at the first `'\0'` character. However, your code doesn't explicitly assign any `'\0'` character, so we can't guarantee that `obuff.code` and `obuff.name` *are* strings. If they're not, the behaviour is undefined (or *erratic*, as I like to describe). Perhaps you meant to use `%15s` and `%50s` respectively, to express that they *might* be strings but that there's a maximum length if they're not?

**This is also where your compilation errors come from. Notice how in previous fragments of code you referred to `obuff->code`**, `obuff->name`, etc **while in this fragment you've referred to `obuff.code`, etc**? The `.` operator accesses the field of a structure while the `->` operator accesses the field of a pointed-at structure... Perhaps you meant to use the `->` operator here, instead?

Comment: Why we shouldn't use `&` before `obuff->code`? I thought it is good to pass a pointer to the entire array beause the parameters says that `fread()` should read *one* element of size `sizeof(obuff->code)`, which should mean the entire array.

Comment: Also why not stop using `malloc()` and simply use usual variable like  `Product obuff;`?

Comment: @MikeCAT It is an unnecessary character, and we should be teaching people why and when it is necessary to use the address-of operator, rather than teaching people to always use the address-of operator for `fread` because *magic*. Regarding your `malloc` suggestion, you raise a good point there; automatic storage duration should most certainly be used in this case.

Comment: @MikeCAT Consider how using the address-of operator here might erroneously translate to using the address-of operator for functions like `scanf` and `fgets`, where providing the wrong type of argument might cause warnings or error messages. If warnings occur, we should be teaching people to analyse them rather than *Ohh, well, I was taught to always use the address-of operator so what does the compiler know?*. This is the kind of error we can avoid by teaching people when it's necessary and when it's unnecessary to use the ampersand.

Comment: Another problem with using `&` blindly with arrays is also that one could think one should 'use it for that `Product foo[]` variable from function arguments because it is an "array" too'.

Answer (score 0):

As referenced by http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm, you have to pass pointers to fread:

```
 size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
```

Your first argument to fread is not a pointer;

```
 fread(obuff->code ...
```

Comment: `obuff->code` is indeed not a pointer, however it is an array... Expressions denoting arrays will be implicitly converted to pointers that point at the first element of the array. The reference you've used is neither authoritarian (use opengroup or one of the three C standards) nor does it set a good example (in examples it ignores the return value of `fopen` and prints a potential non-string as though it's a string, both of which lead to common problems asked about here on StackOverflow). Which book are you reading? I can recommend K&R 2E.

Answer (score 0):

> Please pay attention to the fread()'s definition, The first argumnet need to be one pointer.; And another litter mistake is we need to make use of "->" to get the element in printf() Function.
>
> Below are my modification:

```
void reading(FILE *fp){

  Product *obuff = malloc(sizeof(Product));
  fread(obuff->code, sizeof(obuff->code), 1, fp);
  fread(obuff->name, sizeof(obuff->name), 1, fp);
  fread(&obuff->quantity, sizeof(obuff->quantity), 1, fp);
  fread(&obuff->price, sizeof(obuff->price), 1, fp);   

  printf("%s %s %d %.2f\n", obuff->code, obuff->name, obuff->quantity, obuff->price);
}
```